# Hedge fund rank on their returns or rating predictions modeling problem

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model

**Problem:**

Hi, I m a new machine learning practitioner. I have a dataset about hedge funds. It contains monthly hedge fund returns and some financial metrics. I calculated metrics for every month from 2010 to 2019 December. I want to predict or ranking or rating hedge funds returns basis on these metrics for next month. In other words, for a better explanation, in January 2013, fund A had the highest return and ranked first. which metrics have had an impact on this return potential, how much increase or change in which metrics had an impact on this highest return, how much of which metric increased or decreased, and what caused this result? so I want to find out what the relationship or association is between metrics and return potential. I am open to your suggestions and advisories as to what method or approach should be followed in modeling and editing this data set. I could not find many sources on the internet about this because I could not decide which approach this project looks like, whether it is a recommendation system or a credit rating & scoring or segmentation problem. What does this look like?

**Sample Dataset:**

[image: sample dataset table]

**My Idea:**

my modeling idea is to add a new column to the dataset and write the monthly return ranking of each fund here. Repeat this for all past months and update it monthly. Then select this column as the target variable and estimate or classify it in this way. To use the Random Forest algorithm for this idea. And of course, I'll drop the return column. Do you think this approach will work?

[image: my modelling idea]

I request your help.

**Additional Questions:**

1)
I think this data set is a time series or cross-sectional data so it is necessary to do Nested cross-validation to this data set. How should the data be split correctly?

2)
Do you think it is necessary to normalize the data?

3)And the last question is, what kind of encoding would you suggest for hedge fund's names?